# How to do a many to many query in Flask-SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask and SQL-Alchemy to create an API for my Android Applicaiton. I have a MySQL Database with tables set as such:

```
symptoms:
|    _id     |    symptom     |

food_categories:
|    _id     |    food_categories   |

food_recommendation_type:
|    _id     |    food_categories   |

symptom_food_relationship: (This table is association table relating all three)
|     id     |       symptom_id     |   food_category_id  | food_recommendation_type_id  |
```

In my Flask Application i have mapped out each table:

```
symptom_food_relationship_table = db.Table('symptom_food_relationship',
                       db.Column('id', db.Integer),
                       db.Column('symptom_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('symptoms._id')),
                       db.Column('food_category_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('food_categories._id')),
                       db.Column('food_recommendation_type_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('food_recommendation_type._id')))

class Symptom(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'symptoms'
_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
symptom = db.Column(db.String(100))
symptom_food_relationship = relationship("Food_Categories",
                                         secondary=symptom_food_relationship_table)

class Food_Categories(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'food_categories'
_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
food_categories = db.Column(db.String(30))

class Food_Recommendation_Type(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'food_recommendation_type'
_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
food_recommendation_type = db.Column(db.String)
```

The table looks as such:

```
id symptom_id food_categoryid food_recommendation_id
1   1          2                    1
11  1          8                1
21  1          0                3
31  1          3                3
```

My question the query I would use to change those values into their names. To query one table I would say results = Symptom.query.all(). I know the SQL statement to accomplish this is...

```
SELECT s.symptom, fc.food_categories, fr.food_recommendation_type
FROM symptoms AS s 
INNER JOIN symptom_food_relationship AS srt
INNER JOIN food_categories AS fc
INNER JOIN food_recommendation_type AS fr
ON s._id = srt.symptom_id
AND fc._id = srt.food_category_id
AND fr._id = srt.food_recommendation_type_id
WHERE s._id='1'
ORDER BY s.symptom, food_categories
```

What is the SQL alchemy query statement that is equivalent to that. So I can structure it in a JSON Response.

Answer (score 0):

you want to come up with something like this:

```
results = (session.query(Symptom)
              .join(Symptom. symptom_food_relationship)
              .values(Symptom.symptom,
                      Food_Categories. food_categories,
                      Food_Recommendation_Type.food_recommendation_type))
```

And the results are collected somehow like this:

```
resultlist = []
for username, message, time in results:
    resultlist.append({'symptom': symptom,
                       'food_categories': food_categories,
                       'food_recommendation_type': food_recommendation_type})
```

There may be more elegant ways to come to your data structure but this one should work.

Best if you read the documentation for this issue:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join

good luck :)

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. But when I make this call I see the Symptoms, Food Categories come up correctly, but they are duplicated for each value in the Food Recommendation Type table. Food Recommendation type consists of 3 values (Increase,Limit,Avoid). When I query a symptom with a filter where symptom_id =1 the results should be 4 arrays, but it spits out 12 (4 * 3 recommendations) because it is triplicating the recommendation type for each recommendation. Idk how to set up my symptom class to relate both category and rec, right now it is just  connected to Food_categories

Comment: Whe I understan you correctly, then for this is the returnlist. with that you combine all your tableresults into 1 list.